# Kotlin null propagation syntax not working

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to safely invoke some callback properties but the IDE/compiler is complaining about the syntax.

> Reference has a nullable type '(() -> Unit)?', use explicit '?.invoke()' to make a function-like call instead

#### Property declaration:

```
var onTick: ((millisUntilFinished: Long) -> Unit)? = null
var onFinish: (() -> Unit)? = null
```

#### Invocation:

```
override fun onFinish() {
    // syntax #1
    if (parent.onFinish != null)
        parent.onFinish()
}

override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
    this.millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished
    // syntax #2
    parent?.onTick(millisUntilFinished)
}
```

#### Specifications:

- OS: Windows
- Kotlin version: 1.4.0-rc
- Android Studio: 4.0.1

So far, my best option is to use `lateinit var` but that seems to be inappropriate in my case.

Comment: Would be simplest to change the declarations to be non-nullable, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin compiler is aimed for supporting null-safety even in mutlithreading case.
There is no guarantee that after `parent.onFinish != null` check, it was not set to `null` in some other thread, so smart cast is not working here.

As compiler says, use explicit '?.invoke()':

```kotlin
parent.onFinish?.invoke()
```

```kotlin
parent.onTick?.invoke(millisUntilFinished)
```

Comment: Dang it. I got confused with the syntax. I was doing the `null propagation` on the non-nullable `parent` variable while I should be doing it on its property instead. Thanks for your answer :)